# Is there anyway to use multiple try and one catch?

Tags: java, c#, android, c#-4.0

I have the following code with multiple try...catch, is there any way to make it simpler?

```js
try {
    saveToInternalStorage(((BitmapDrawable) image1.getDrawable()).getBitmap(), imageFilename + "_1");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    saveToInternalStorage(((BitmapDrawable) image2.getDrawable()).getBitmap(), imageFilename + "_2");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    saveToInternalStorage(((BitmapDrawable) image3.getDrawable()).getBitmap(), imageFilename + "_3");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    saveToInternalStorage(((BitmapDrawable) image4.getDrawable()).getBitmap(), imageFilename + "_4");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: A for loop may be better for you!

Comment: The code seems strange. If the first "saveToInternalStorage" fails, this seems to be regarded as unusual enough to print a stack trace.  But then we carry on and call "saveToInternalStorage" for the second image.  It is hard to believe the program is achieving anything useful by essentially ignoring errors.  A single try/catch has more obvious semantics: give up on first failure.

Comment: You should almost never `catch Exception`; instead, catch the more meaningful class (`IOException`) that you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you wrote is really the appropriate logic, then:

```
private void trySave(Whatever image. String file) {
   try {
       saveToInternalStorage(image.getDrawable().getBitmap(), file);
   } 
   catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

and call as

```
trySave(image1, imageFilename+"_1)";
trySave(image2, imageFilename+"_2");
trySave(image3, imageFilename+"_3");
trySave(image4, imageFilename+"_4");
```

Subroutines reduce repetition.

Answer (score 2):

Yes... However the concerns raised in the comments are valid

1. Why do you need to do this
2. Why are you happy for this to fail
3. Why are you ignoring the errors
4. If 1 failed wouldn't it be good to have them all fail

All that aside. here is a splattering of code

```
var array = new[]{ image1, image2, image3, image4 };

for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
   try
   {
      saveToInternalStorage(array[i].getDrawable().getBitmap(), $"{imageFilename}_{i + 1}");
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting those images from 4 different image button that's why I can't use "for" and I don't care if one or more was empty.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the multiple try catch,you can just put the try catch block into the saveToInternalStorage then if you dont care about the error just use finally instead of catching.
its faster to not catch since it doesn't track the error thrown.

```
// example 1  if you are not interested in the error or the success responce

void saveToInternalStorage(BitmapDrawable bd, String file_name)
{
    try{

    //..put your code here

    }finally{


    }

}
// example 2 if you are interested in just geting the success response  

 boolean saveToInternalStorage(BitmapDrawable bd, String file_name)
{
    try{

 //..put your code here

 return true;
    }finally{
     return false;
    }

}
// example 3 if you are don't want to touch your saveToInternalStorage function 

 boolean saveToInternalStorage(BitmapDrawable bd, String file_name)
{
    try{
    saveToInternalStorage(bd,file_name)

return true;
    }finally{

 return false;

}

}
```